# Trying to crop an image in ffmpeg using alphamerge but produces wrong alpha

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using alphamerge in order to crop an image within a circle.

What I have so far is:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "color=c=white:size=240x240" -i avatar.png -i mask.png -filter_complex \
 "[1][2]alphamerge[img]; \
 [0][img]overlay[out]" -c:v png -map "[out]" -pix_fmt rgba -t 5 -y out.mp4 2>&1
```

with avatar.png and mask.png respectively being:

[image: avatar] [image: mask]

This produces the following output (1 frame of the output video):

[image]

which is unexpected, given the original input is much darker than this.

How can I crop the 'avatar.png' using the 'mask.png' so that the output is the avatar.png cropped in a circle and keeping the same alpha?

PS: The important bit here is for me to be able to crop the original image and maintaining the correct colors/apha of the original image. If there is an other way of doing this (other than alphamerge) I am happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
ffmpeg -i avatar.png -i mask.png -filter_complex "[0]scale=400:400[ava];[1]alphaextract[alfa];[ava][alfa]alphamerge" output.png
```